# Зависает чтение InputStream

Tags: java

Пытаюсь прочитать длинный InputStream (с ~180к+ символов)
Этим способом зависает в while:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

int length; 
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
    baos.write(buffer, 0, length); 
}
System.out.println(baos.toString());
```

Пробовал другие способы, но нужно обязательно записывать данные в ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: он не зависает, он читает...

Comment: он не перестает читать

Comment: в данном куске кода я не вижу проблем. Попробуйте добавить вывод прочитанного текста в консоль, на каждом этапе чтения (внутри while). Если и правдв чтение зависает, то в консоли вы это увидите. Если прочто долго читает - это тоже увидите

Comment: Это первое, что я попробовал. Первую итерацию он вывел, а на второй застрял на проверке условия и ни в цикле, ни за его пределами вывод в консоль уже не проходит.

Comment: тогда разделите этапы чтения и записи. Проверьте на каком зависание. попробуйте прочитать несколько раз без цикла.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в сокете есть столько данных?